# Better alternative to nested loop

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, nested, nested-loops

I'm currently writing a program that needs to compare similar strings with Damerau levenshtein algorithm in an ArrayList of ArrayList of String. Right now, the way I'm doing this is through a nested code loop:

```
Damerau d = new Damerau();

for(int i = 0;i<outer.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    String cstring = outer.get(i).get(5);
    for(ArrayList<String> current : outer) {
        if(d.distance(cstring , current.get(5)) < 30){
            //System.out.println(cstring);
            outer.get(i).set(0, current.get(0));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is really slow as the arraylist consists of 33000 string arraylists.

Comment: If you're reading data from database then instead of fetching all data only pull required data. SQL queries are comparatively faster than line by line compare. In case you're not using RDBMS then I would suggest having at least sqlite dump data and fetch data using queries.

Another thing is use some profiler tool and identify which line is exactly consuming more and more time. If possible try splitting data in smaller lists and independent threads.

Comment: Have you benchmarked your code to see where the most time is spent? One optimization could be to only fetch `outer.get(i)` once within the outer loop instead of fetching it in every inner loop iteration.

Comment: What about tagging the value you have already checked to skip them ? instead of only setting the `out.get(i)` you could update`current` too if it matched.

Comment: If you're comparing similar strings, have you tried sorting the data?

Comment: @phflack the algorithm compare similarities in `String` not similar `String`, so `Zen` and `Ten` are Similar with a distance of 1. You can't order that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your code correctly you do something along the lines of this:

```
for each outer as cstring : 
    for each outer as current:
       levenshtein(cstring, current)
```

which means you make tons of unnecessary comparisons. Assuming you have a list with strings `[a, b, c]`, the combinations you are testing are `[aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc]`. This includes comparisons with themselves (`aa, bb, cc`), which is always 0, as well as calls to the levenshtein function with swapped parameters (`ab,ba,ac,ca,bc,cb`), which are always identical. So if you skip identical pairs and self testing, you only need to test the combinations `ab,ac,bc`. You could achive this in your code pretty easily by starting your inner loop on i+1.